# Qual modo posso usar expressão regular pra capturar apenas alguns atributos de links

Tags: javascript, html, regex, loop, link

Preciso de exemplo(s) básico de como poderei elaborar um minúsculo *script* pra pegar apenas o conteúdo do(s) *atributo* `href`.

Vou simplificar a explicação em dois grupos, são eles: ***A*** e ***B***

No *Grupo A* temos os respectivos links iniciado com *slash* `/` precedido da palavra - ***manga***. Ja para o *Grupo B* temos os mesmo setindo, com detalhe que a palavra ali associada ao código é ***caqui*** diferente de manga.

Então fica assim:

**Grupo A**

```
<a href='/manga?v=1234567890'>A</a>
<a href='/manga?v=1234567890'>A</a>
<a href='/manga?v=1234567890'>A</a>
```

etc...

**Grupo B**

```
<a href='/caqui?v=1234567890'>B</a>
<a href='/caqui?v=1234567890'>B</a>
<a href='/caqui?v=1234567890'>B</a>
```

etc...

> Como fazer para tratar um desses grupo trazendo a frente na página somente os links referente ao código ***manga***? Os demais não deve vir a aparecer.

**Atenção!** - *Todos eles não tem `class` e nem `id`, mas possue em seu atributo valores idênticos se comparado ao mesmo grupo pertencente do mesmo segmento. Eu só quero **manga**.*

Então vamos lá!

Eu tenho feito o laço pra percorrer o elementos sobre a *tag* `a`, ele me retorna todos links existentes na página. Veja:

```
var link = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {

    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML+= "<br>"+link[i].getAttribute('href')+"<br>"

}
```

O que peço aqui, é a junção do `link[i].getAttribute('href')` com uma expressão regular

```
function ExtrairID(url){
    var regExp = /^.*((manga\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    var match = url.match(regExp);
    if ( match && match[7].length == 10 ){
        return match[7];
    }else{
        alert("Não foi possível extrair a ID.");
    }
}
```

Já fiz algumas tentativas por conta própria, dai acabei me perdendo então resolvi vir aqui pergunta. Sem mais, aguardo resposta ou breve explicação.

Comment: O tamanho é sempre o mesmo ? 10 dígitos ?

Comment: Por mais que funcione com regex, o recomendado para trabalhar com HTML é a utilização de um DOM para Javascript (Ou outro automatizador web). Muitas vezes você pode se deparar com situações que um simples Regex não será o suficiente.

Comment: @danieltakeshi Desculpe mas, não compreendo o que você quis me passar. Poderia por gentileza ser mais claro sobre o assunto?

Comment: O que vc quer dizer "trazendo a frente na página"?

Comment: Vc quer pegar todos os `href` que tem manga?

Comment: @DvD Isso mesmo o que você entedeu. =)

Comment: O que eu quis explicar, é que Regex não é o mais recomendado. E a resposta do dvd é mais recomendado... com  `.getAttribute("href");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma opção sem usar regex, apenas verificando se no `href` tem a palavra **manga**:

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll("a");
var resultado = '';
for(var x=0; x<els.length; x++){
   var href = els[x].getAttribute("href");
   resultado += href.indexOf("manga") != -1 ? href : '';
}
console.log(resultado);
```

```html
<a href='/manga?v=1234567890'>A</a>
<a href='/manga?v=1234567890'>A</a>
<a href='/manga?v=1234567890'>A</a>
<a href='/caqui?v=1234567891'>B</a>
<a href='/caqui?v=1234567891'>B</a>
<a href='/caqui?v=1234567891'>B</a>
```

Ou pode usar o seletor específico, sem usar `indexOf`:

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='manga']");
var resultado = '';
for(var x=0; x<els.length; x++){
   resultado += els[x].getAttribute("href");
}
console.log(resultado);
```

```html
<a href='/manga?v=1234567890'>A</a>
<a href='/manga?v=1234567890'>A</a>
<a href='/manga?v=1234567890'>A</a>
<a href='/caqui?v=1234567891'>B</a>
<a href='/caqui?v=1234567891'>B</a>
<a href='/caqui?v=1234567891'>B</a>
```

Comment: Ficou bom d+ foi criativo em usar o _método_ `indexOf()`. Pena que isso nem me passou pela cabeça.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro faz o [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) para verificar se na *URL* contém `/manga`

- **\d** Somente dígitos
- **{10}** Limita de 10 dígitos

```js
var LINKS = document.querySelectorAll('a');
var RESULTADO = document.querySelector('#resultado');

function extrair(url) {
  // Verifica se contém '/manga'
  if (/\/manga/.test(url)) {
    RESULTADO.innerHTML += /\d{10}/g.exec(url) + "<br>";
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < LINKS.length; i++) {
  extrair(LINKS[i].getAttribute('href'));
}
```

```html
<h3>Grupo A e B</h3>
<a href='/manga?v=4533567894'>A</a>
<a href='/caqui?v=1234567490'>B</a>
<a href='/manga?v=7634567890'>A</a>
<a href='/caqui?v=1234567888'>B</a>
<a href='/manga?v=2345567899'>A</a>
<a href='/caqui?v=1234567234'>B</a>

<h3>Resultado da Expressão Regular - Grupo A</h3>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

**ECMAScript 5**

```js
let LINKS = document.querySelectorAll('a');
let RESULTADO = document.querySelector('#resultado');

const extrair = (url) => {
  // Verifica se contém '/manga'
  if (/\/manga/.test(url)) {
    RESULTADO.innerHTML += /\d{10}/g.exec(url) + "<br>";
  }
}

LINKS.forEach((link) => {
  extrair(link.getAttribute('href'));
});
```

```html
<h3>Grupo A e B</h3>
<a href='/manga?v=4533567894'>A</a>
<a href='/caqui?v=1234567490'>B</a>
<a href='/manga?v=7634567890'>A</a>
<a href='/caqui?v=1234567888'>B</a>
<a href='/manga?v=2345567899'>A</a>
<a href='/caqui?v=1234567234'>B</a>

<h3>Resultado da Expressão Regular - Grupo A</h3>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

> **Obs.:** Creio que aja maneira mais simples, ainda estou aprendendo, dúvidas, sugestões, pode comentar.

Comment: O erro que aparece no **console**, na verdade é o **alert** que você criou na condição **if** fiz essa alteração porque fica aparecendo muito **alert** ao testar a função. Veja que dentro da função que criei tem a linha **console. error** só alterar para ser **alert**, quanto ao navegador não sei, pois nunca usei, no momento estou pelo celular, não tem como testar. Mas procura no **Google** sobre o assunto.

Comment: Esta retornando como você descreveu, ele não esta retornando o **Grupo B** somente o **A**.

Comment: Aqui testado localmente, a saída no console do Navegador Palemoon da nisso - **LINKS.forEach is not a function**

Comment: Vou ajeitar, o **Google Chrome** funciona.

Comment: São essas semânticas mordenas demais, pra alguns navegadores funciona que é uma beleza mas outros não, isso sem levar em conta, diferentes versões. Por isso gosto de programar no modo antigo com `loop` ao invés de `querySelector` e `forEach`. Embora [ECMAScript](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) se esforce em padronizar, ainda esta longe atingir todos os navegadores como ocorreu com HTML5 e CSS3. Ou seja, só vejo essas semânticas serem úteis nos dias de hoje em aparelhos móveis que ja saem de fábrica contudo pra rodar essas síntaxe, pra PC domésticos só vai vale no futuro tanto próximo

Answer (score 2):

Pode facilmente obter todos os links com um href que começa com `/manga` com o seletor CSS:

```
a[href^='/manga']
```

Usando [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
links = document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='/manga']");
```

Além disso, todos os [HTMLAnchorElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement) (as `<a>`) têm a propriedade [.search](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/search) que retorna a string de consulta (desde o `?` em diante).

Então, use esta regex para obter o valor do parâmetro `v`:

```
[?&]v=(\d+)
```

Código:

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='/manga']"),
    x,
    re = /[?&]v=(\d+)/,
    m;

for (x of links) {
    if (m = re.exec(x.search)) {
        console.log(m[1]);
    }
}
```

```html
Grupo A e B:
<a href='/manga?v=1234567890'>A</a>
<a href='/manga?v=1234567891'>A</a>
<a href='/caqui?v=1234567892'>B</a>
<a href='/caqui?v=1234567893'>B</a>
<a href='/manga?v=1234567894'>A</a>
<a href='/caqui?v=1234567895'>B</a>
```

Comment: Legal, tai algo que desconhecia semântica nova[CSS].

Answer (score 1):

No lugar do `match[7]` use `match[3]`

entrada: `ExtrairID("aaaa/manga?v=1234567890")`

```
function ExtrairID(url){
    var regExp = /^.*((manga\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    var match = url.match(regExp);
    console.log(match);
    if ( match && match[3].length == 10 ){
        return match[3];
    }else{
        alert("Não foi possível extrair a ID.");
    }
}
```

match resultado:

```
["/manga?v=1234567890", "/manga?", "/manga?", "1234567890", index: 0, input: "/manga?v=1234567890"]
0 : "/manga?v=1234567890"
1 : "/manga?"
2 : "/manga?"
3 : "1234567890"
index : 0
input : "/manga?v=1234567890"
```

return `1234567890`

Edit:

```
var link = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < link.length; i++) { 
  ExtrairID(link[i].getAttribute('href')) 
}
```

Comment: editei o loop agora voce so precisa implementar o resto

Comment: da para fazer tudo numa funcao so mas ai cabe a vc decidir o que voce quer